# Why is setTimeout firing earlier than it should?

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverside-javascript

I have a bit of node.js code as such:

```
var start = Date.now();

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(Date.now() - start);
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    }
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(Date.now() - start);
}, 2000);
```

Something strange happens when I run it on my machine. The times I get are something between 970 and 980, and something between 1970 and 1980. Why am I getting times that are earlier than the timeout times?

Comment: In which browser? Safari returns numbers like 1002 and 2001, similar in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: First of all you should remove that `for` loop – using constructs like this in JS is never a good idea. There is no equivalent of a `sleep` function in JS, and trying to create a similar effect using such long-running loops is utter nonsense that will in almost all cases lead to unpredictable or unreliable results.

Comment: I get 1002 and 2002 respectively.

Comment: This is just example code, and I am actually running this on my linux machine, not running it in any browser. I have that loop in there simply to simulate an event which takes time.

Comment: The Date object isn't intended to be particularly accurate, some implementations only have a 15ms precision. Consider using [*performance.now*](http://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/#dom-performance-now) ([*MDN link*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now())) if supported.

Comment: I ran your code on node.js on Windows and got two numbers I would expect: `1015` and `2001` which are pretty much when the two timers are set to fire.  Right now, I'd say your numbers are not reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the node.js `setTimeOut` [documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/timers.html#setTimeout):

> It is important to note that your callback will probably not be called
>   in exactly delay milliseconds - Node.js makes no guarantees about the
>   exact timing of when the callback will fire, nor of the ordering
>   things will fire in. The callback will be called as close as possible
>   to the time specified.

However, there is a nanotimer to play with:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/nanotimer

Some related questions:

- [node.js setTimeout resolution is very low and unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317717/node-js-settimeout-resolution-is-very-low-and-unstable)
- [Why does node.js handle setTimeout(func, 1.0) incorrectly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288050/why-does-node-js-handle-settimeoutfunc-1-0-incorrectly)

However, I do think +/- 30ms early is a bit much (compared to most *browsers* I've played with, they are usually no more than 10ms *later* (as long as the cpu isn't maxed out, that is)).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're experiencing these issues because of the Date precision. It can vary across platforms and browsers.

[Here](http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/)'s a more detailed read on the accuracy of Date.

There are more high precision timers [available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now()) on some platforms, but you will often have to do some mix and match (detect what's available and regress accordingly).